# How to convert a list in to categories with sub items in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to convert the following in to expectedResult?

```
const items = [
      { type: 'fruits', index: 1, name: 'FRUITS' },
      { type: 'fruit', index: 2, name: 'orange' },
      { type: 'fruit', index: 3, name: 'apple' },
      { type: 'fruit', index: 4, name: 'banana' },

      { type: 'vegetables', index: 5, name: 'VEGETABLES' },
      { type: 'vegetable', index: 6, name: 'ginger' },
      { type: 'vegetable', index: 7, name: 'tomato' },
      { type: 'vegetable', index: 8, name: 'potato' },
      { type: 'vegetable', index: 9, name: 'garlic' },
      { type: 'vegetable', index: 10, name: 'cucumber' },

      { type: 'meats', index: 11, name: 'MEATS' },
      { type: 'meat', index: 12, name: 'Beef' },
      { type: 'meat', index: 13, name: 'Chicken' },
      
   ...so on
    ];
```

In to this:

```
    const expectedResult = [
      {
        type: 'fruits',
        index: 1,
        name: 'FRUITS',
        items: [
          { type: 'fruit', index: 2, name: 'orange' },
          { type: 'fruit', index: 3, name: 'apple' },
          { type: 'fruit', index: 4, name: 'banana' },
        ],
      },

      {
        type: 'vegetables',
        index: 5,
        name: 'VEGETABLES',
        items: [
          { type: 'vegetable', index: 6, name: 'ginger' },
          { type: 'vegetable', index: 7, name: 'tomato' },
          { type: 'vegetable', index: 8, name: 'potato' },
          { type: 'vegetable', index: 9, name: 'garlic' },
          { type: 'vegetable', index: 10, name: 'cucumber' },
        ],
      },

      {
        type: 'meats',
        index: 11,
        name: 'MEATS',
        items: [
          { type: 'meat', index: 12, name: 'Beef' },
          { type: 'meat', index: 13, name: 'Chicken' },
        ],
      },
         ...so on
    ];
```

So the idea is to look for the `type` and then look for the next indices till the index changes the `type` and move those indices in to a sub array like `items: []`

for example for item  `type: 'fruits'` check for the consecutive proceeding indices till type changes to  `type: 'vegetables'` and copy those in-between indices in to `type: 'fruits', items: [... in to this array]` array.

**Idea is to look for consecutive in-between indices and copy them in to `items: []` sub array.

Comment: Simply loop your array and construct new one

Comment: How can I do it to look for next encounter of type changes the copy that to ```items: []``` sub array?

Comment: The parent and children have the same key, the only difference is in the cases and plural form, would suggest to better key to distinguish, otherwise errors may occur for huge dataset.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to map an array of objects in to a different one based on criteria?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66454159/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-in-to-a-different-one-based-on-criteria)

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the items. Set the current item type and add the item to the expected list. Subsequent items that match that type get added to that item. Repeat otherwise.

```js
const items = [
  { type: 'fruits', index: 1, name: 'FRUITS' },
  { type: 'fruit', index: 2, name: 'orange' },
  { type: 'fruit', index: 3, name: 'apple' },
  { type: 'fruit', index: 4, name: 'banana' },

  { type: 'vegetables', index: 5, name: 'VEGETABLES' },
  { type: 'vegetable', index: 6, name: 'ginger' },
  { type: 'vegetable', index: 7, name: 'tomato' },
  { type: 'vegetable', index: 8, name: 'potato' },
  { type: 'vegetable', index: 9, name: 'garlic' },
  { type: 'vegetable', index: 10, name: 'cucumber' },

  { type: 'meats', index: 11, name: 'MEATS' },
  { type: 'meat', index: 12, name: 'Beef' },
  { type: 'meat', index: 13, name: 'Chicken' },

];

var type, expected = [];

for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
   if(type && 0 <= type.indexOf(items[i].type)) {
      expected[expected.length - 1].items.push(items[i]);
   } else {
      type = items[i].type;
      items[i].items = [];
      expected.push(items[i]);
   }
}

console.log(expected);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can divide these items into two arrays like this and then go from there...

```js
const items = [
      { type: 'fruits', index: 1, name: 'FRUITS' },
      { type: 'fruit', index: 2, name: 'orange' },
      { type: 'fruit', index: 3, name: 'apple' },
      { type: 'fruit', index: 4, name: 'banana' },

      { type: 'vegetables', index: 5, name: 'VEGETABLES' },
      { type: 'vegetable', index: 6, name: 'ginger' },
      { type: 'vegetable', index: 7, name: 'tomato' },
      { type: 'vegetable', index: 8, name: 'potato' },
      { type: 'vegetable', index: 9, name: 'garlic' },
      { type: 'vegetable', index: 10, name: 'cucumber' },

      { type: 'meat', index: 11, name: 'MEAT' },
      { type: 'vegetable', index: 12, name: 'Beef' },
      { type: 'vegetable', index: 13, name: 'Chicken' },
    ];
const group = items.reduce((acc,it)=>{
 if(it.type.toUpperCase()===it.name){
  acc.cats.push(it)
 }else{
 acc.subs.push(it)
 }
 return acc;
},{cats:[],subs:[]});
console.log(group)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a reduce function to reformat your object:

```js
items.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const availableTypes = Object.keys(acc)
  if (!acc[item.type] && !availableTypes.some((type) => type.indexOf(item.type) === 0)) {
    return acc[item.type] = { ...item, items: [] }
  } else {
    const currentType = availableTypes.find((type) => type.indexOf(item.type) === 0)
    return acc[currentType] = {
      ...acc[currentType],
      items: acc[currentType].items.concat(item)
    }
  }
}, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const items = [
          { type: 'fruits', index: 1, name: 'FRUITS' },
          { type: 'fruit', index: 2, name: 'orange' },
          { type: 'fruit', index: 3, name: 'apple' },
          { type: 'fruit', index: 4, name: 'banana' },
          

          { type: 'vegetables', index: 5, name: 'VEGETABLES' },
          { type: 'vegetable', index: 6, name: 'ginger' },
          { type: 'vegetable', index: 7, name: 'tomato' },
          { type: 'vegetable', index: 8, name: 'potato' },
          { type: 'vegetable', index: 9, name: 'garlic' },
          { type: 'vegetable', index: 10, name: 'cucumber' },

          { type: 'meats', index: 11, name: 'MEAT' },
          { type: 'meat', index: 12, name: 'Beef' },
          { type: 'meat', index: 13, name: 'Chicken' }
        ];
        
      
        let expectedResult = [];
        items.forEach(function(element){
            var parentItem = expectedResult.findIndex(ele => ele.type == element.type+'s' );
          if( parentItem >= 0){
            expectedResult[parentItem].items.push(element);
            return;
          }
          element.items = [];
           expectedResult.push(element);
            });
        console.log(expectedResult);
```