# How to map an array of objects in to a different one based on criteria?

Tags: javascript

How to map an array of objects in to a different one based on criteria?

How to convert the following array of questions in to expected array?

```
const questions = [
                { type: 'question', index: 1 },
                { type: 'question', index: 2 },
                { type: 'answer', index: 3 },
                { type: 'answer', index: 4 },
                { type: 'answer', index: 5 },
                { type: 'answer', index: 6 },
                { type: 'answer', index: 7 },
                { type: 'answer', index: 8 },
                { type: 'answer', index: 9 },
                { type: 'question', index: 11 },
                { type: 'answer', index: 12 },
                { type: 'answer', index: 13 },
                { type: 'question', index: 14 },
                { type: 'question', index: 15 },
                { type: 'question', index: 16 },
                { type: 'question', index: 17 },
                { type: 'answer', index: 18 },
                { type: 'answer', index: 19 },
                { type: 'question', index: 20 },
                { type: 'question', index: 21 },
                { type: 'question', index: 22 },
                { type: 'question', index: 23 },
                { type: 'question', index: 24 },
                { type: 'question', index: 25 },
                { type: 'question', index: 26 },
                { type: 'question', index: 27 },
                { type: 'question', index: 28 },
                { type: 'question', index: 100 },
                {}
          ];
```

This is the expected array of results.

```
                    const expected = [
                      { type: "question", index: 1, answers: [] },
                      {
                        type: "question",
                        index: 2,
                        answers: [
                          { type: "answer", index: 3 },
                          { type: "answer", index: 4 },
                          { type: "answer", index: 5 },
                          { type: "answer", index: 6 },
                          { type: "answer", index: 7 },
                          { type: "answer", index: 8 },
                          { type: "answer", index: 9 },
                        ],
                      },

                      {
                        type: "question",
                        index: 11,
                        answers: [
                          { type: "answer", index: 12 },
                          { type: "answer", index: 13 },
                        ],
                      },

                      { type: "question", index: 14, answers: [] },
                      { type: "question", index: 15, answers: [] },
                      { type: "question", index: 16, answers: [] },
                      {
                        type: "question",
                        index: 17,
                        answers: [
                          { type: "answer", index: 18 },
                          { type: "answer", index: 19 },
                        ],
                      },

                      { type: "question", index: 20, answers: []},
                      { type: "question", index: 21, answers: []},
                      { type: "question", index: 22, answers: []},
                      { type: "question", index: 23, answers: []},
                      { type: "question", index: 24, answers: []},
                      { type: "question", index: 25, answers: []},
                      { type: "question", index: 26, answers: []},
                      { type: "question", index: 27, answers: []},
                      { type: "question", index: 28, answers: []},
                      { type: 'question', index: 100, answers: [] },
                      {}
                    ];
```

So the idea is to have a sub array called `answers` in to which we push the in-between items with `type === 'answer'`.

So the answers should be pushed to the index `n-1` with `type === 'question'` till the next item with type `type === 'question'` is encountered. If there are no answers in-between then keep the array empty.

**Basicallly we look for the index and type**

**Update**

So the way I tried was I created an array containing the indices. And each time I looped through I looked for the next maximum index and it's type. Later based on that I tried copying the in-between indices to the previous index.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself?

Comment: Yes. But it's not working. It's failing.

Comment: What was wrong with [the answers that you got last time you asked this question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66453207/how-to-convert-a-list-in-to-categories-with-sub-items-in-javascript)

Comment: Then _show us_ what you tried anyway, and give a _proper_ problem description along with it (“it’s failing” is not one.) All of this is explained in [ask].

Comment: (And have you asked one single question on this site yet, where you did _not_ start the title with “How to …”? I would say this is a pretty strong indicator, that you should learn to do your own basic research at some point, instead of outsourcing this to the community on such a massive scale.)

Comment: Who is upvoting this... It's lacks effort and the OP has asked the exact same question twice. This (and [the copy and paste other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66453207/how-to-convert-a-list-in-to-categories-with-sub-items-in-javascript)) should be closed... OP, please read the [help]

Comment: And “show us what you tried” means _code_ (plus explanation, as far as necessary), and _not_ just a totally vague verbal description of what you supposedly tried.

Comment: No. Please . I'm missing something. Please help. I have suggested the idea above. But not sure what is missing.

Comment: Put some effort in yourself. We're not a code writing service for you.

Comment: This is a different question.

Comment: It's 100% not..

Comment: You should show us your code which is failing next time. You couldn't keep on relying on the community to do this kind of stuff for you.

Comment: I haven't asked questions on SO for a while, even when I'm stuck. I only tried solving them by myself. But in this case I'm stuck. That's why I've asked. @Liam

Comment: Ok > @LengLong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just imagine how you would filter it as a person and then use the same way for the code.

1. You would definitely check all the elements in that array, so you need to use a loop, and then just filter and push it into the new 'expected'array.

This is how I would do it.

```js
const questions = [
        { type: 'question', index: 1 },
        { type: 'question', index: 2 },
        { type: 'answer', index: 3 },
        { type: 'answer', index: 4 },
        { type: 'answer', index: 5 },
        { type: 'answer', index: 6 },
        { type: 'answer', index: 7 },
        { type: 'answer', index: 8 },
        { type: 'answer', index: 9 },
        { type: 'question', index: 11 },
        { type: 'answer', index: 12 },
        { type: 'answer', index: 13 },
        { type: 'question', index: 14 },
        { type: 'question', index: 15 },
        { type: 'question', index: 16 },
        { type: 'question', index: 17 },
        { type: 'answer', index: 18 },
        { type: 'answer', index: 19 },
        { type: 'question', index: 20 },
        { type: 'question', index: 21 },
        { type: 'question', index: 22 },
        { type: 'question', index: 23 },
        { type: 'question', index: 24 },
        { type: 'question', index: 25 },
        { type: 'question', index: 26 },
        { type: 'question', index: 27 },
        { type: 'question', index: 28 },
        { type: 'question', index: 100 }
    ];

//filtering array expected
    let expected = [];
    for (let i of questions){
        if (i.type === "question"){
            expected.push({
                type: i.type,
                index: i.index,
                answers: []
            })
        } else if (i.type === 'answer'){
            let index = expected.length - 1;
            expected[index].answers.push(i)
        }
    }



    console.log(expected);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `reduce` here. Here's what on my mind.

```js
const questions = []; // your questions here

questions.reduce((acc, question) => {
  if (question.type === 'question') return [...acc, Object.assign({}, question, { answers: [] })];
  else if (question.type === 'answer') {
    return [
      ...acc.slice(0, acc.length-1), 
      Object.assign({}, acc[acc.length-1], {
        answers: [...acc[acc.length-1].answers, question]
      })
    ];
  }
}, []);
```

Well, the code looks unpretty and not really readable. I suggest changing the data structure of your `questions` if it is possible to make the code prettier.

Comment: TypeError: acc[(acc.length - 1)] is not iterable. Getting this error.

Comment: Sorry, I'm actually typing it directly without trying it out. Give me a moment, I'll try it out on my machine.

Comment: Can u please check the expected result ```const expected``` and kindly update the answer?

Comment: I'm not asking to do all my work. This is the only piece I'm stuck with. Pleas try to understand that.